# How to test touch dialog and perform real in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have submitted my iOS app. The status is now pending developers release . In-app auto renewable subscriptions are approved. When I test, the app still prompt sandbox dialog for me to enter sandbox account password to verify my purchase. I cannot test real purchase and cancel under this situation . Would you please tell me what is the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test in-app in Production environment, not Sandbox, you need to have the appropriate build.
If you are running from Xcode, you are automatically acting in Sandbox.

To have a Production environment, you need to make an AdHoc build (distributed via services like diawi.com) or AppStore build (distributed via Testflight).

Comment: I have uploaded my App Store build onto the browser. I have applied a cloud function to verify my receipt. Why does the app still prompt sandbox dialog and request my user to login ?

Comment: How did you make AppStore build and what do you mean by "uploaded onto the browser"?

Comment: That means uploading my build to App Store

Comment: Did you then try to make the purchase in this freshly downloaded version? Or in the app installed via Xcode?

Comment: Do you mean the Testflight Version? If I find something wrong in Testflight mode, how can I debug?

Comment: I mean AppStore version. You just said you’ve uploaded the app to the AppStore.

Comment: OK, That means if I export the App Store Version, the app is already pointing to the production fields while IAP. Testflight user can use real account for testing IAP?

Comment: Yes. But of course you won't be able to debug it with app attached to Xcode. Once you launch from Xcode, the app is in Sandbox again.